# PowerApps: what flow/process to use?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I'm trying to find a way to accomplish my use case in PowerApps, but haven't been really successful so far. I'll describe what I'm trying to achieve:

Story: There are students and exam courses for them to participate in. The courses contain multiple time periods. Students can choose which time period would suit them best and what subject they are interested in. According to the students chosen time periods, a calculation* has to be made to establish which time periods will remain and what subjects will be teached in these time periods, and the time periods that aren't chosen can be disposed of.

Tables:
Student
Student_TimePeriod (timeperiod, preferred subject, student)
TimePeriod

*This calculation is what I'm struggling with. I've tried multiple types of flows but always end up concluding it can't do what I want. The calculation has to take all the Student_TimePeriod records in account, and filter those to find 'winning' TimePeriods, which after that sets the status of the remaining TimePeriods to a permanent status AND decide what subject will be teached in that period.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction? Thank you very much in advance!

I've tried: Cloud flow, Action, Business Process Flow.

Comment: In general these kind of requirements cannot easily be met using "low code" technology. Preferred approach here is developing a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, your goal is to group the records based on timeperiod, sort groups by count of records and take the top 1 group. Then group the records based on subject and take the top 1 subject.

Here's an implementation of this logic in Power Automate:
https://www.flyingpolymath.com/post/group-by-and-sum-in-power-automate